# jQuery height/outerheight broken when using img tags in Webkit?

Tags: jquery, image

I think I found a bug in webkit: FF doesn't have a problem reporting the height of this image, but webkit will only show the height here at 0. If there a fix for this other than specifying the height in CSS? I have a few images with the same width, but different heights.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var rowTitleWidth = $('.art').height();
   alert(rowTitleWidth);
})

<img class="art" src="images/channel_art/channel_hd.png" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works fine for me. You might want to take a look into jquery images loaded plugin though, it may be an issue with ready() being fired before the image has downloaded.

Comment: Ah, I get it. You were kinda right. The fix is to use .load first, then run the rest as a function of .load.

Comment: Great! Glad you could figure it out. Dont forget to check as answered :)